# Get the id passed to to the form action in Scala without creating multiple forms

Tags: html, forms, scala, playframework

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="ticket">
  @for(t <- tickets) {
    @form(routes.TicketsController.delTicket(t.id), 'class -> "form-inline") {
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="ticket">
          @t.name 
          <button type="submit" class="close form-control" value="X">X</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    }
  }
</ul>
```

I need to pass the id (without making it visible in the HTML) to the form action without creating as many forms as there are records (or in other words get the form out of the loop, but still get the right id). I guess it's an easy task, but I can't think of a good solution.

Comment: You cannot pass the `id` to the `delTicket` action if it is not in the HTML. If you want to be able to delete every ticket, you need a form for every ticket. Maybe you need to rephrase your question ?

Comment: You can use hidden text field `<input type="hidden" name="idlist[]" value="12">` Then read the array `idlist`? Or I do not understand your question...